# silverlight 4 with java service

Tags: java, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i intent to replace wcf service with some java service . how should i design my wcf service such that it's gets replaced or can be replaced with the java service later such that i dont have to do any work or very little work on the client i.e on my silver light application .

any idea's / suggestions?

P.S 
1. that is the reason i am not using RIA services. 
2.my wcf service should work like wcf data services work. it should allow me to do CRUD operations on my entities.

Comment: A bit more informatin would be helpful -- why are you going to be switching back-end service? Silverlight and WCF are a designed to work together. I don't think switching to java is a good idea, if ou need to have a java service, start with java.

Comment: well there are many reasons , first of all i dont want the clients of my software to be micrsosoft server dependant , i mean they can go with linux as well .
since linux is free , cost of the deployment shall go down by big scale.
thank you forthe enquiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create java services using Apache CXF or Apache Axis.  Deploy those services in Tomcat server.  You can easily create client proxies for those services by using adding service reference in Silverlight Client application.   Now you can consume the webservice from silverlight.

Comment: thanks for the response .
asking another out of context .unlike microsoft technologies , apache , java , linux are all free even if used commercially?

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer is this: use the BasicHttpBinding on the service. Don't add anything else to it. Most other stacks support BasicHttpBinding just fine.

Alternatively, use a WCF REST endpoint and standardize on consuming JSON. Then, your service can be PHP, Ruby, Java, or anything else.

Comment: thanks for the answer . 
what i intent to do is , convert c# code to java (using any convertor ) and than simplay put all my service method in a java class and make the methods available on the service . 
i think this is fairly good approach ?
secondly , can you roughly provide some step i should take on the java end , once the code is converted .
say i am going with WCF Rest approach ( i think this is a bit better).

Comment: I believe the point of the first paragraph, was USE the C# service, but stick with BasicHttpBinding as this **DOES NOT REQUIRE WIDNOWS CLIENTS** to connect -- otherwise WCF REST and then it will be easier to swap out back ends.